# Motorcycle won't stay on when in gear

Tags: engine, motorcycle, ignition, yamaha

I've had a motorcycle sitting and it wouldn't start. After charging the battery and using fuel injector cleaner, the motor stays running but only in neutral.

I called my local repair shop and the mechanic said the problem is that I've been using gasoline. I can see how maybe sediment gets the engine dirty but he wouldn't tell me how to fix it and said that his shop doesn't do that specific work.

The motorcycle is a Yamaha V-Star 250.

Comment: To clarify, when you put the vehicle in any gear it immediately stalls, is this correct?

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Sticking clutch?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Or a side side stand kill switch.  Could be either.

Comment: Could also possibly be the clutch safety switch if equipped.

Comment: This might also be an intended function, have you tried it with the side stand in the up position I.E put the side stand up then engage a gear?

Answer (score 3):

If it instantly dies when you put it in gear, even when holding the clutch (and the clutch is operational, which you can know if it doesn't jerk forward when you shift into gear when holding the clutch), it's almost certainly the kickstand safety switch. You should see a physical switch of some kind that makes contact with the kickstand when it's either down or up.

You can bypass this pretty easily, but it's actually a useful safety switch, and it's ideal to replace or repair it.